# C++ eclipse gives "Invalid Arguments" for const parameter

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I am using Eclipse Luna 2 CDT and having a wierd issue with indexer. The indexer fails with "const" for parameter. I am using C++11 and other c++11 functions work fine.

Sample Class

```
class Test {
public:
    int getX();
}
```

this works with no issue in eclipse

```
void method(Test& t) {
    t.getX();
}
```

This gives wierd invalid arguments exception:Invalid arguments 
'Candidates are:int getX()'

```
void method(const Test& t) {
    t.getX(); //ERROR: Invalid arguments in eclipse
}
```

My question is why can Eclipse not work with const parameter. This works find with the build gcc build with no issue.

Comment: not answer your question.there is a problem of C ++ syntax, keywords Class, letter c must be lowercase, remove the brackets.

Comment: fixed the sample code

Comment: const t only can call const function. fix like this: int getX() const;

Comment: hmm that worked. Wonder why my clang compiler work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C ++ compiler, in order to prevent you from accidentally modifying objects, constants can not call non-const object suffix method.

we can fix like this:

```
int getX() const;
```

const object and non-const object both can call it.

why clang compiler work,maybe a clang issue(we could search later) or some optimization leads to ignore checking.

**ADD:**

**9119**    clang   C++     unassignedclangbugs     RESO    DUPL    **no error calling non-const method on const object** and something else.

I think this is clang issue,new version maybe fix.